# where to set counter for login attempts

Tags: node.js, angular, express-session

A basic question:
I have an angular site with Login page and captcha. I need to activate the captcha only after 3 attempts to login.
I have a counter for this. Locating it in the component itself won't work because refreshing the page is setting it to 0; 
I wonder can I store it in the login service - concerning whether it will be a common to all the users reaching the service, which will be a problem - Am  I correct ?
(The other option is to store it as a variable of the session (express-sesion) - this should probably work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum...
I assume that when the user is login in, the front make a http call to your back-en to check is the user/password couple is correct because all the security must be on back-end side.
Knowing that, I'd say that the counter must also be on the back-end side.
If you put the counter on the front side, a simple refresh of the page or a clear of the browser storage, will bypass your counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in express-session, if session is started even for not authorised users. Otherwise, you should store counter by username in some database. Try [rate-limiter-flexible](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible) for that. You can make your login system even more robust with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've investigated it, here are my conclusions:
There are 2 optional answers to this question:
1. If you (I...) want to have the counter in the context of the client, meaning  -whenever I leave the browser and open a new one - the counter will be reset, and only in this specific browser I will get the captcha afetr 3 tests, then it should be managed in the sessionStorage. 
2. If you want to have a persistence between browsers, meaning no mater what window browser (from the same kind, i.e.- chrome, IE or FF) will you open - the counter is shared between them and if you have a captcha triggered from one of them it will appear in all, when refresh them - then you can manage it in the express-session as @animir mentioned